# Populate multicolumn listbox with sql query recordset having multiple rows

Tags: vba

```
Private Sub Combo13_AfterUpdate()
    Dim v1 As Variant: Dim i,i3, i1, i2 As Integer: Dim rst As Recordset
    v1 = Combo13.Value  'combo13 is the list box
    Set v1 = CurrentDb("Bills")   'bills is the table name
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select *  from bills where billnumber = " & Combo13.Value & ";")
    i1 = "select count(*) from bills where billnumber = " & Combo13.Value & ")"
    i2 = rst.Fields.Count
    For i = 1 To i1
        For i3 = 1 To 12
        With List6
             .AddItem rst.Fields(i2).Value 
              rst.MoveNext
        End With
        Next i2
    Next i1
    Set rst = Nothing   
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: `Set List6.Recordset = rst`

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs a lot improvement
That said, this is a syntax error

```
i1 = "select count(*) from bills where billnumber = " & Combo13.Value & ")"
```

The closing `)` is incorrect syntax

Also `i1` is a string - the query in the string is not being executed anywhere - you need to execute and extract `i1` value from the resulting recordset, similar to the code on the previous line `... CurrentDb.OpenRecordset ...`

`Dim i,i3, i1, i2 As Integer` Only declares `i2` as an integer. if you want all to be declared as integers it should be

```
Dim i As Integer,i3 As Integer, i1 As Integer, i2 As Integer
```

Comment: pl give an example for populating listbox from sql query result having multiple columns and rows

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub Combo13_AfterUpdate()
Dim s1, s2 As String: Dim i, i1, i2, j As Integer: Dim rst As Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select *  from bills where billnumber = " & Combo13.Value & ";")
rst.MoveLast
i2 = rst.RecordCount
i1 = rst.Fields.Count
On Error Resume Next
For i = List6.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
List6.RemoveItem (i)
Next i
i = 0
rst.MoveFirst
For i = 1 To i2
With List6
For j = 1 To i1
s2 = s2 & rst.Fields(j) & ","
Next j
.AddItem s2
rst.MoveNext
End With
s2 = ""
Next i
End Sub